# Spring Hibernate generate dynamic query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using hibernate spring where I need to generate query on a condition.

DAO.java

```
public ReturnData updateUserDetails(Users users, String mailID)
{
    if(!users.getImageURL().equals(""))
    {
        Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("UPDATE users SET emailID=:email_ID, name=:name, imageURL=:imageURL WHERE emailID=:emailID")
        //setString....

    }
    else
    {
         Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("UPDATE users SET emailID=:email_ID, name=:name WHERE emailID=:emailID")
        //setString....

    }
}
```

In the above code, I check if image also has been uploaded or not. On the basis of this condition, I have to dynamically generate query. I have to rewrite the whole code for query+execution 2 times. Is it the good way, or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: does ImageURL column allow null values ?

Comment: @Bhushan, yes, it does allow null values. Suppose, if old value present in the column, it will put null on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically append the query conditions to the query string if they are not null. After getting the final list of conditions, you can create Hibernate query.

```
        StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder();
        Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        boolean isFirstSearchCriterion = true;
        sqlQuery.append("UPDATE users");


        if(email_ID!= null && !email_ID.trim().equals("")) {
            if(isFirstSearchCriterion) {
                sqlQuery.append(" set emailID= :email_ID");
            } else {
                sqlQuery.append(" and emailID= :email_ID");
            }
            parameters.put("email_ID",email_ID);
            isFirstSearchCriterion = false;
        }

        if(name!= null && !name.trim().equals("")) {
            if(isFirstSearchCriterion) {
                sqlQuery.append(" set name= :name");
            } else {
                sqlQuery.append(" and name= :name");
            }
            parameters.put("name",name);
            isFirstSearchCriterion = false;
        }

        if(imageURL!= null && !imageURL.trim().equals("")) {
            if(isFirstSearchCriterion) {
                sqlQuery.append(" set imageURL= :imageURL");
            } else {
                sqlQuery.append(" and imageURL= :imageURL");
            }
            parameters.put("imageURL",imageURL);
            isFirstSearchCriterion = false;
        }


          Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(sqlQuery);


        Set<String> parameterSet = parameters.keySet();
        for (Iterator<String> it = parameterSet.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            String parameter = it.next();
            query.setParameter(parameter, parameters.get(parameter));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do without checking empty String, if user has image url it will add in column or else empty url will be pass on.

```
public ReturnData updateUserDetails(Users users, String mailID)
{
    Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("UPDATE users SET emailID=:email_ID, name=:name, imageURL=:imageURL WHERE emailID=:emailID")
       query.setParameter("imageURL",users.getImageURL(), Hibernate.STRING);

}
```

Comment: I cant do this as it will update already present imageURL with null.

Comment: you can go for Criteria Query and conditionally add add Criteria to the Query.